# Datastore contention on new deployment with the same code

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify, contention

We're having some issue with our application that uses Datastore (not Firestore in Datastore mode) after redeploying the code. On the new AppEngine service deployment with the same code we get Datastore contention issues and if we switch to the old service version (same code) everything works just fine. Triple checked this as we still have the deployment logs and it's the exact same commit on both the deployments.

We've tried everything, rolled back other services, tried to lower the queue's throughput, attempted to upgrade some dependencies and nothing seems to fix it.

For info the app is using GAE Datastore API and Objectify v5.

Any idea of why something like this might happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't much here to help you out.  E.g. code samples.  You could consider enabling [data access logs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/audit-logging#audited_operations) on your writes to see if there is a change to your datastore accesses change with your code deployment.